# Luke 3:9- can μὴ in "not bearing good fruit" have an exegetical clue if the tree was bad by nature and kind, or from its laxity?

Tags: luke

Is Matt. 7:19 -"Every tree that does not bear good fruit is cut down and thrown into the fire"- a parallel verse?

John, the Baptist was addressing to the "children of Abraham" (v.7) and in v. 8, said "Bear fruits in keeping with repentance. And do not begin to say to yourselves, ‘We have Abraham as our father.’ For I tell you, God is able from these stones to raise up children for Abraham."

Text: Luke 3:9 (ESV)

"Even now the axe is laid to the root of the trees. Every tree therefore that does not bear good fruit is cut down and thrown into the fire.”

Comment: I am not sure the language can be pressed that far.

Comment: @Dottard, I agree. However, the context can shed a clear light: as verse 8,  ποιήσατε (bear - imperative, 2nd. Plural) shows the "trees" -capable of bearing the fruits. A "bad tree" by kind/nature cannot respond to the imperative.